# How to extract strings between two fixed marks repeatedly

Tags: python, python-re

suppose we have a string
`text="xaxbx"`
We try to get everything between "x". In this case the answer should be "a" and "b"
But when I try

```
result=re.findall('x(.*?)x',text)
```

I only get `"a"`, but not `"b"`
Is there a solution for more generalized situations such as
`text="xaxbxcxdxexfx"`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `re.findall('x(.*?)x',text)` the characters "x" are consumed in the process of making a match. You can use lookahead and lookbehind instead:

```
import re

text="xaxbx"
re.findall(r"(?<=x)[^x]+(?=x)", text)
```

It gives:

```
['a', 'b']
```

Answer (score 1):

That is, because you "consume" the `x`'s by matching them directly. Look up [lookahead and lookbehind](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html). Using these features you get the correct solution:

```
(?<=x).*?(?=x)
```

Try it on [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/wi8IgS/1), you can test example strings there and they explain each part of the regex.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to use regular expression grouping:

```
import re

text = "xaxbxcxdxexfx"
re.findall("x([^x]+)", text)
```

Output:

```
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']
```